# Can't hard code left margin for custom redefinition of itemize environment

Tags: enumitem, latex3

The `enumitem` docs show the following figure:

[image]

I'm trying to redefine the `itemize` environment such that I can go several levels of nesting beyond the default. I would like indent each new nesting level at a distance similar to the one before it. So based on the figure above I think `\leftmargin` is the correct variable to use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont, graphicx}

\let\oldlabelitemi\labelitemi
\let\oldlabelitemii\labelitemii
\let\oldlabelitemiii\labelitemiii
\let\oldlabelitemiv\labelitemiv

\setlistdepth{9}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\oldlabelitemi, leftmargin=25pt}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=\oldlabelitemii, leftmargin=30pt}
\setlist[itemize, 3]{label=\oldlabelitemiii, leftmargin=35pt}
\setlist[itemize, 4]{label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{117}}, leftmargin=40pt}
\setlist[itemize, 5]{label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{110}}, leftmargin=45pt}
\setlist[itemize, 6]{label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{115}}, leftmargin=50pt}
\setlist[itemize, 7]{label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{108}}, leftmargin=55pt}
\setlist[itemize, 8]{label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{53}}, leftmargin=60pt}
\setlist[itemize, 9]{label=\oldlabelitemiv, leftmargin=65pt}

\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item 1
  \begin{itemize}
  \item 2
    \begin{itemize}
    \item 3
      \begin{itemize}
      \item 4
        \begin{itemize}
        \item 5
          \begin{itemize}
          \item 6
            \begin{itemize}
            \item 7
              \begin{itemize}
              \item 8
                \begin{itemize}
                \item 9
                \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

However when I compile this, the left margin seems to increase for every new level of nesting:

[image]

Why does this occur and how do I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Try setting `leftmargin=10pt` for all, then you'll get the idea. It is not setting the margin from the left side of the overall text block but in relation to the current (list) indentation and since you are using increasing values for `leftmargin` the spacing grows.

Comment: Think of the list as a box. For the next nested list, the preceeding box acts as the `preceeding text` of the image you show. This box gets narrower and narrower for each nesting level.

Comment: I see, though if I don't set the `leftmargin` for all levels at all, I still get what appears to be arbitrary spacing from the left. But setting all of them to `25pt` does the job for now. Thanks,[

Comment: I would not say it is arbitrary if you remove them, all the "non-standard" levels have the same default indentation whereas the traditional levels have a class dependent (probably) default indentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set global settings for the whole list including all levels and then use starred version `\setlist*` only to alter individual levels. For instance, in the code below, I only alter labels but you could also change `leftmargin` etc.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{pifont, graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\let\oldlabelitemi\labelitemi
\let\oldlabelitemii\labelitemii
\let\oldlabelitemiii\labelitemiii
\let\oldlabelitemiv\labelitemiv
\setlistdepth{9}
\renewlist{itemize}{itemize}{9}
\setlist[itemize]{
  align=left,
  leftmargin=*,         % or use fixed length like 0.5em etc.
  listparindent=1.5em,  % indentation for subsequent paragraphs 
  label=\scalebox{0.7}{\ding{117}}, % Default label
}
\setlist[itemize, 1]{label=\oldlabelitemi}
\setlist[itemize, 2]{label=\oldlabelitemii}
\setlist[itemize, 3]{label=\oldlabelitemiii}
\setlist[itemize, 9]{label=\oldlabelitemiv}


\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
\item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
  \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1] 
    \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1] 
      \begin{itemize}
      \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
        \begin{itemize}
        \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
          \begin{itemize}
          \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
            \begin{itemize}
            \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
              \begin{itemize}
              \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
                \begin{itemize}
                \item \kant[2][1]\kant[3][1]
                \end{itemize}
              \end{itemize}
            \end{itemize}
          \end{itemize}
        \end{itemize}
      \end{itemize}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]